# VBA Picture Shadow Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a bunch of images that I would like to apply a specific picture style to - the 4th one that is shown in Word 2010:

[image: picture style toolbar]

I have a macro that will loop through all images, but need to know the possibilities for the shadow.type .

What would be really helpful is a reference to the commands that would be used for each type of picture style, with a visual example.

I don't have VBA, so can't examine the elements of the picture. I have tried various msoShadowxx, but that didn't work.

Is there a good reference with visual examples, or a reference with the settings for each picture style? Or the settings to use for the 4th picture style (shown in the screenshot here)?

Here is the macro code that I use to loop through all the pictures.

```
Sub BorderMacroshadow()
Dim oInlineShp As InlineShape
For Each oInlineShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
With oInlineShp
    .Line.Weight = 1
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
    .Shadow.Type = msoShadow14
End With
Next
End Sub
```

**Added**

A closer look at the reference for msoShadow shows that it is referring to Picture Effects, Shadows 'dialog', not the 'Picture Styles', which I assumes uses some elements of msoShadow in addition to other elements.

So, I am looking for the elements that are needed to duplicate the 4th 'Picture Style' (see the screenshot). Haven't found those yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have VBA so can't examine the elements of the picture"?

Comment: How about the language reference for the MsoShadowType - did you read that? It says "The msoShadowType constants are numbered according to their order (left to right, top to bottom) within the Shadow Style set shown in the Drawing toolbar."

Comment: @CindyMeister : I did see that reference, but when I tried msoShadow4 the result did not look like the 4th Picture Style. In fact, none of the choices for the numbering order (left-to-right, top-to-bottom) matched the visual choices on the Picture Style bar.

As for 'inspecting the element' - I couldn't find the ability to do that in Word2010, so assumed it was a Visual Basic application choice,which I don't have. 

So was hoping for a more correct syntax for the #4 Picture Style; or a reference that was correct.

Answer (score 3):

The `msoShadowType` enumeration is a group of pre-sets. These aren't necessarily used in the gallery on the Ribbon.

In order to ascertain the settings of any Shadows formatting use the various properties available for `Shape.Shadow`, such as `Transparency`, `Size`, `Blur`. Inthe UI, these can be seen in Picture Effects, Shadow, Shadow Options of the Picture Style group on the Ribbon.

To determine/set them programmatically, see the following code sample. Note that `Angle` is not one property, but a combintation of `OffsetX` and `OffsetY`.

```
Sub ShadowProperties()
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim shw As Word.ShadowFormat

    Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    Set shw = shp.Shadow
    With shw
      Debug.Print "Blur: " & .Blur, _
                "size: " & .Size, _
                "Transparency: " & .Transparency, _
                "Offset x: " & .OffsetX, _
                "Offset y: " & .OffsetY
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Older question - but now that I have Word 2019, is there an update to this answer because of new features/capabilities in Word 2019?  https://stackoverflow.com/users/3077495/cindy-meister